# Best way to add a background to an activity

Tags: java, android, layout

I don't want to add new elements to my xml , but I can change values. I don't care about code ase soon as I dont have to append a huge chunk on a place.

I tried adding a background but this actually had the picture with a great amount of padding.....

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your title:

Get the ID of the parent layout and use the `setBackground(##DRAWABLE##)` method to set the `Activity` background.

Comment: The setBackground centers the image with a padding.